# Cannot build permalink for GET varIable

Tags: php, wordpress, get, taxonomy, permalinks

I use taxonomy "gallery" with slug "albums". In my WP I have the template gallery-albums.php page which used for the both situations: 1. the user gets the page with gallery albums; 2. after click the user passes to one album with some gallery posts. That all is in one page gallery-albums.php. In order to define which part of code to execute I use GET variable ?album=title-of-album. If this GET variable exists we load page with one album, else it loads the list of albums.

So, I have the code for separate album: `http://mysite.com/page_id=2688?album=some-albume`.

I needs to use permalinks. When i set custom permalink structure /%category%/%postname%/ I get the link: `http://mysite.com/albums/?album=some-albume`. "Albums" is a name of page with template gallery-albums.php.

I need a link: `http://mysite.com/albums/one-albume` or `http://mysite.com/album/one-albume`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As i understand from you that you are asking about rewrite purposes so take look to this : http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

hope this will help you :)

Comment: No, I really know basic info about permalinks. The question is how to pass GET variable through permalink structure in order my template could work with this variable.